# Oracle query to fetch the count of distinct records based on another query's output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a Oracle table (FILE_RECS) which has data in the following format:

```
file_name              record      time                       issue
C:/work/file.csv       234RCV      2017-04-10 02.50.35        RCM0001
D:/new/file.csv        235RCV      2017-04-09 07.20.59        RCM0002
D:/new1/file1.csv      235RCV      2017-03-08 09.28.19        RCM0002
D:/new/file1.csv       236RCV      2017-04-09 03.32.54        RCM0002
C:/new/file.csv        237RCV      2017-04-09 23.24.18        RCM0002
```

The file names are the same but the path is different. I need to fetch the number of distinct records in every file.
My final output should be something like this:

```
FILE_NAME              Number of records
file.csv               3
file1.csv              2
```

I was able to parse the file name using the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT substr(S,instr(file_name,'\',-1)+1,length(file_name)-instr(file_name,'\',-1)) AS FILE_NAME FROM (select DISTINCT file_name from FILE_RECS);
```

Not sure on how to approach for the original request.

Could someone help me how to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Just `group by` the extracted file_name.

```
SELECT substr(file_name,instr(file_name,'/',-1)+1,length(file_name)-instr(file_name,'/',-1)) AS FILE_NAME
,COUNT(*) as number_of_records
FROM FILE_RECS
GROUP BY substr(S,instr(file_name,'/',-1)+1,length(file_name)-instr(file_name,'/',-1))
```